# How to programmatically include link to a facebook page (Android)?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

My app has a feature that posts a photo + text to a user's facebook wall (works fine).  Now I'm trying to include a link in the text that goes to a specific facebook page (doesn't work).

The basic code looks like this (works fine):

```
private void postImageToFacebookWall(String filePath, String msg) {
try {
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param = new Bundle();

    // prep photo byte array
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    // add byte array and user msg
    param.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
    param.putString("message", msg);

    // post to Facebook
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new PostRequestListener(), null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to embed a link to a facebook page in the msg, using the following syntax:

```
    @[fb_page_id:str]
```

This works when I type it directly into facebook.  But it doesn't work when I use it in the code, modified as follows (doesn't work):

```
String fbPageRef = "@[" + Constants.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID + ":str]";
param.putString("message", msg + " " + fbPageRef);
```

When I run the code with the embedded link (fbPageRef), it doesn't show up.

**What am I doing wrong?**  Thanks.

Comment: Note: a reference for the syntax of linking to a page id can be found here: [How do you link to a Facebook Page in a comment using its PageId?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/how-do-you-link-to-a-facebook-page-in-a-comment-using-its-pageid).  As noted above, this works if directly typed into facebook, but not when sent by my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't notice at first that a facebook post generated by an app already includes an attribution to the source app.  It's at the bottom of the post and reads something like: **"2 hours ago via YourAppName"**.

This is friendly to read, and correctly links back to the app's facebook page (assuming there is one).  So if that's good enough, you don't have to worry about how to insert a link in the text part of the post!

Still it would be good to know how to embed a link to a facebook page in a machine-posted message (?).  Thanks.